# error on passing data for edit to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to pass an object of model class for edit but receing this error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type **'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication1.Models.ResturantReviews]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.ResturantReviews'."**

Kindly guide me where I am wrong, here is my code:

**My Model class:**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models{
public class ResturantReviews
{

        public int ReviewId { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public string ReviewBody { get; set; }
        public Resturant Resturant { get; set; }

}
```

}

**My Action code:**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
    {
        //var review = FoodDB.review;
        ResturantReviews obj = new ResturantReviews {
          ReviewId = 2,
            Rating = 9,
            ReviewBody = "Test Sarina is a good resturant for continantal food",
            Resturant = new Resturant
            {
                ResturantId = 1,
                ResturantAddress = "Commercial area",
                ResturantName = "Sarina Hotel"

            }
        };



        return View(obj);
    }
```

**My code in View:**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ResturantReviews

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ResturantReviews</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReviewId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReviewId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewBody)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReviewBody)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReviewBody)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Edit controller action (as shown in your question) passes a single instance of `ResturantReviews` and the view is strongly typed to `@model ResturantReviews` so this should not throw an exception. The code seems correct as is.

So you could try narrowing down by simplifying at maximum:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
{
    var model = new ResturantReviews();
    return View(model);
}
```

and the `Edit.cshtml` view:

```
@model ResturantReviews
@Html.BeginForm()
{
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>    
}
```

This should work 100%. Then you could start adding functionality.